# Autofixture - create a float, double or decimal with remainder

Tags: c#, tdd, autofixture

How do I modify AutoFixture create method for float, double and decimal, so that when these types get created they will also have a remainder?

Currently I do this, but this throws exception.

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<double>(sb => sb.FromFactory<double>(d => d * 1.33));   //This should add remainder
var value = fixture.Create<double>();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Attempting to redefine a type (`double`) by using a value of the same type (`double`) will, indeed, yield an infinite recursion. However, you can easily make this work by changing the seed input into another type - e.g. an `int`:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<double>(c => c.FromFactory<int>(i => i * 1.33));
var value = fixture.Create<double>();
```

Doubles will now tend to have fractional values too.

Comment: I guess I haven't really thought about how things work in the background and that customization was creating an infinite recursion. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: I didn't realize AutoFixture generates only integral floating point numbers! that seems completely odd/wrong. I just wrote my own `CreateDecimal`, etc. extension methods that add `Random.NextDouble()` to the result, but I've been using `Create<decimal>` for some time assuming the results would have fractional parts.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use a custom `ISpecimenBuilder`:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new RandomDoublePrecisionFloatingPointSequenceGenerator());
```

The `RandomDoublePrecisionFloatingPointSequenceGenerator` could look like below:

```
internal class RandomDoublePrecisionFloatingPointSequenceGenerator
    : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly object syncRoot;
    private readonly Random random;

    internal RandomDoublePrecisionFloatingPointSequenceGenerator()
    {
        this.syncRoot = new object();
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var type = request as Type;
        if (type == null)
            return new NoSpecimen(request);

        return this.CreateRandom(type);
    }

    private double GetNextRandom()
    {
        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            return this.random.NextDouble();
        }
    }

    private object CreateRandom(Type request)
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(request))
        {
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                return (decimal)
                    this.GetNextRandom();

            case TypeCode.Double:
                return (double)
                    this.GetNextRandom();

            case TypeCode.Single:
                return (float)
                    this.GetNextRandom();

            default:
                return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nikos thanks for the help, but Mark's answer is more inline with what I was searching.

Comment: +1 Any reason for making this SpecimenBuilder thread safe - do you do this for all your builders? (I understand why a Random needs to be guarded bit it never occurred to me to add this guarding in a SpecimenBuilder. I'd never though of Fixture and/or Generators emanating from same as being guaranteed threadsafe. I certainly can understand how, esp given @ploeh's Immutability work in V3.0 that it might be relatively easy enough to achieve). Or have I missed a blog post :P

Comment: +1 This one could also work without the thread safety. Almost all numeric sequence generators are thread safe though.. Most of them (if not all) were created prior to 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to intercept/modify created values, but a solution I think I prefer is to use a second `Fixture`.

```
public static IFixture FixDecimals(
   this IFixture me
) {
   var f = new Fixture();
   var r = new Random();
   me.Register<float>(() => f.Create<float>() + r.NextSingle());
   me.Register<double>(() => f.Create<double>() + r.NextDouble());
   me.Register<decimal>(() => f.Create<decimal>() + (decimal)r.NextDouble());
   return me;
}
```

I think 'normally' you could use something like the following, but it doesn't work in these cases because these are value types.

```
// doesn't work
var r = new Random();
me.Customize<float>(f => f.Do(_f => _f += r.NextSingle()));
```

This doesn't work because `Do` isn't a function but wants you to modify the 'instance', but since these are value types, modifying the 'instance' does nothing because we have a value not an object instance.